# Angular: How to trigger change detection (OnPush) on click event?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have following Angular (v11) component containing a Material table with virtual scrolling:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="50" class="wrapper mat-elevation-z2">
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="items">
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name" [sticky]="isNameSticky">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        <button *ngIf="item.isExpandable" (click)="onButtonClicked(item); item.isLoading = false;">
          <div class="button__icon">
            <app-spinner [class.hide]="!item.isLoading"></ptrn-spinner>
            <app-icon-chevron-down [class.hide]="item.isExpanded || item.isLoading"></ptrn-icon>
            <app-icon-chevron-up [class.hide]="!item.isExpanded || item.isLoading"></ptrn-icon>
          </div>
        </button>
        <a>{{ item.name }}</a>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Info Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="info">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Info</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.info }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" [class.hide]="row.isHidden"></tr>
  </table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
`,
styleUrls: ['./app-table.component.scss'],
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
 ...
 
 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
 
 onButtonClicked(item: Item): void {
   item.isLoading = true;
   this.cd.detectChanges();
   runLongRunningScript(item);
   this.cd.detectChanges();
 }
```

When clicking on the button it supposed to expand several other rows (like a tree list).
To do this it calls a function that could run a second or two.
In order to communicate with the user that something is running in the background I would like to remove the chevron icons with a spinner.
But the current solution does not work. It seems the change detection only runs after everything within the click event is completed.

How do I accomplish this?

**Update:**
I included the use of the detectChanges() method of the ChangeDetectorRef, but it still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried injecting changeDetectorRef, and trigger detectChanges() ?

Comment: How about to inject ChangeDetectorRef to this component, and trigger detectChanges() or markForCheck()?

Comment: @FatihErsoy I included it in the code, but still the same behavior.

Comment: one thing I would try is to replace the class.hide approach with ngIf's.
I'm not sure where/if css comes in to play with change detection, but template directives for sure should.

Comment: @iamaword I tried ngIf's but it didn't work either

Comment: add a breakpoint/ debugger; statement before and after the updates to see if maybe it's somehow related to the variables task.isExpanded  and task.isLoading